# how to fix 504 gateway timeout error in Gunicorn

Tags: python, gunicorn

```
gunicorn app:app -b :8080 --timeout 120 --workers=3 --threads=3 --worker-connections=1000
```

I am new to devops and I am currently using this command to run my app on port 9=8080 but if I receive too many requests I am getting 504 gateway timeout error. I know workers =3 means if three requests come simultaneously they will be processed simultaneously by worker but what is the use of threads and worker connections,

do I need to increase the worker, threads and worker-connection size to prevent 504 from happening?

I need to know is this command correct.
If not how do I modify this so that 504 error should not occur again?

Comment: You can increase timeout of gunicorn workers

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways to fix a 504 gateway timeout error in Gunicorn with Django. One way is to increase the number of workers. Another way is to increase the timeout value.